# Different ways to say to like?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, politeness

On one self-teaching site, I learned to say "to not like" in a format like this: いぬはすきじゃりません。But in a self-teaching *book* it said to format it like this: いぬはすきではありません。I know there are many different ways to say everything in Japanese, but I just want to make sure that both of these are correct! What's the difference between the two? Is one more formal than the other? Are there certain situations in which one is more appropriate than the other?

Comment: Are you sure the second said ～はありません and not ～ではありません?

Comment: Whoops yes, that is what I meant, thank you!

Comment: And the first said じゃ**あ**りません, right?

Comment: @Nothingatall What? Right now it says じゃりません which is what I was talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 犬{いぬ}は好{す}きじゃない。

is a casual colloquial expression.

> 犬{いぬ}は好{す}きじゃありません。

is also a casual colloquial expression, even a little bit polite.

You can say and write the expression with "じゃ" in your e-mail to your friends and family members.

> 犬{いぬ}は好{す}きではありません。

is a polite expression.

Anyway conversation topics of "likes-dislikes" are personal affirs, so you have many occasions to say "ｘｘｘは好きじゃない（=好きじゃありません）" with your friends.

> example: "納豆は食べられるけど、好きじゃないね"

Answer (score 8):

じゃ is simply a contraction of では, so these sentences are equivalent and correct.  じゃ is slightly more familiar/informal than では, but not necessarily rude or anything.  You could probably functionally compare it to `can't` vs. `cannot`.